# Find '.jpg' in src, count letter 8 before than, and cut ir off

Tags: jquery

I have this tag

```
img src="http://www.penacozinha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/cozinha_fit2-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="cozinha_fit2">
```

Auto generated by woocommerce shop.

The problem is: the image is renamed to "image-150x150.jpg", what I need: cut '-150x150',in other words. 
remove 8 letters before '.jpg'.

Like that: image.jpg only in jquery

Comment: Is it always 150x150? What happens if it's 1000x1000? Look into `preg_match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It works with any dimensions.

```
$(function() {
    var images = $('.attachment-shop_catalog');
    $.each($(images), function(idx, item) {
        var src=$(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+/, ''));
    });
});
```

Working jsfiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0pa5zkvf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Can use jQuery `attr( attributeName, function)` to loop through and do replacements

```
$(function(){

    $('.attachment-shop_catalog').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc){
        return oldSrc.replace('-150x150', '')
    });

});
```

Using the function argument of `attr()` will loop over all matching selectors providing index and existing value as arguments.

Reference **[attr( attributeName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)**